# Error in latest version of h2 - Cannot resolve com.h2database:h2:1.4.200

Tags: java, sql, maven, dependencies, h2

Hello I've got a problem with h2 in maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.200</version>
    </dependency>
```

version 1.4.197 is working but 1.4.200 is giving me an error:
Cannot resolve com.h2database:h2:1.4.200
Can you help me?

Comment: Rather not because previous version is working

Comment: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.h2database/h2/1.4.200/jar. ... there is a connection error may be you don't see etc. Please run your build on plain command line ...

Comment: Maybe you are right because today it works idk why but now it's ok. Thank you